# How to detect when QPropertyAnimation finishes?

Tags: qt, animation, qt5, signals, qpropertyanimation

I have a code:

```cpp
void testbutton::buttonPressEvent(bool pressed_arg){
    QPropertyAnimation *animation = new QPropertyAnimation(m_button_bg, "size", this);
    animation->setDuration(500);
    animation->setEasingCurve(QEasingCurve::InCurve);
    int maxwidth = mwidth;
    if(pressed_arg == true)
        {
            animation->setStartValue(QSize(m_button_bg->width(), 39));
            animation->setEndValue(QSize(39, 39));
            pressed = false;
            animation->start();


         }
    else{
        animation->setStartValue(QSize(m_button_bg->width(), 39));
        animation->setEndValue(QSize(maxwidth, 39));
        pressed = true;
        text_button->show();
        animation->start();

    }
}
```

I want the `text_button` to be hidden after the end of the animation from the `pressed_arg == true` option, because the `animation` itself cannot do this due to the fact that this button contains text and cannot be compressed to zero, so I want to track the end of the `animation` and then apply `text_button->hide()`.

How can I do that?

***P.S:*** the animation compresses the frame in which this button is located.

I tried:

```cpp
animation->start();
text_button->hide();
```

but the button disappeared right when the animation started, and it doesn't look like I expected it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[QPropertyAnimation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qpropertyanimation.html) inherits [QAbstractAnimation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qabstractanimation.html) which provides a [finished](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qabstractanimation.html#finished) signal, connect it to a your `text_button`'s `hide` method.

```
connect(animation, &QPropertyAnimation::finished, text_button, &QPushButton::hide );
```

see [this](https://forum.qt.io/topic/63215/how-to-detect-when-animation-completes/2) for more information.